# JBoss Ldap Auth LdapExtLoginModule problem

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, ldap

We are trying to setup Jboss 4 to authenticate users using Microsoft Lightweight Active Directory Service (aka ADAM)

user name: admin
CN=admin,CN=Users,CN=donLaptop,DC=don,DC=com

JBoss can connect to ADAM, but somehow cannot validate the password (fig4)
Using Apache Directory Studio, I can verify that CN=admin,CN=Users,CN=donLaptop,DC=don,DC=com can connect successfully to ADAM(fig5)

jboss config - figure3

ADAM config/ADSI - fig1 and fig2

What am I missing?

Please help

[image: LDS config 1]
[image: LDS config 2]

[image: jboss config]

[image: jboss error]

[image: apache ldap success]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from

http://www.vivit-worldwide.org/groups/viewtopic.php?t=1465

A common value for baseFilter for Active Directory servers is: **baseFilter=CN={0}** or to use the Window NT 4.0 SAM-Account-Name: **baseFilter=sAMAccountName={0}**

I change the baseFilter from baseFilter=sAMAccountName={0} 
to

**baseFilter=CN={0}**

because I am using ADAM, and it works now.